# Balanced Sampling in R with numeric and factor variables

Tags: r, random, cluster-analysis, bigdata

I am working on a project where I would like to implement clustering techniques, but the data is what you would call quite large, ~13mil rows and ~200 coloumns. And thus, way to big for any conventional clustering such as `hclust`.

My idea is to reduce the size of the data by getting a balanced sample of the data. I come across `library(BalancedSampling)` which seems highly efficient on big datasets, problem is, that it seems to only handle numeric variables.

Is there any recommendations on how I would approach this sampling problem in this fashion:

```
library(BalancedSampling)
N <- 10000000
n <- 10000
p <- rep(n/N,N)
X <- cbind(p,apply(t(data.frame(rep(N,123))),2,runif),
           apply(t(data.frame(rep(N,77))),2,function(x) sample(letters,x,replace=T)))
y <- cube(p,X)
```

Also, would `hclust` be appropriate given the new sample size? Or should I go for another clustering algorithm such as `kmeans` with `gower.dist`?

Comment: Can you code your non-numeric as a numeric value?  If you have many different types, you can bin the data with `findInterval`.

Comment: Thanks, so what you are suggesting is taking my factors and frequency variables, converting them into some kind of relating measure so that I can use the `BalancedSampling` methods. That might work. Thank you.